# HTML-events wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am using an event wrapper for my calendar by I want it to be RTLed (Right to Left)
[calendar wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et2lC.png)

and this is the code:

```
<div class="events-wrapper">
  <div class="events">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#0" data-date="16/01/2014" class="selected">Jan </a></li>
      <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: li{display:inline-block;float:right;}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to flip the wrapper to put the arrow on the left side instead of the right side, and the <li>s also

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Day 1</li>
  <li>Day 2</li>
  <li>Day 3</li>
  <li>Day 4</li>
  <li>Day 5</li>
  <li>Day 6</li>
  <li>Day 7</li>
  <li>Day 8</li>
  <li>Day 9</li>
  <li>Day 10</li>
  <li>Day 11</li>
  <li>Day 12</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: My question was how to flip the wrapper to put the arrow on the left side instead of the right side, and the <li>s also.

Comment: ...and where is that explained in the question?

Comment: ...and where do you mention the arrow.? You really need to [edit] the question to explain what it is you want **AND** provide proper code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I added an image you can check it

Comment: We need your HTML & CSS in a demo..images are of little use.